# Should we dual-tag my question?

Tags: discussion

*Some background*: I recently created this question: [Are all events one-shot?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/40228/21486)...
At the time, the [betrayal-at-baldurs-gate](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal-at-baldurs-gate) tag didn't exist and I didn't have the reputation to create it, so I tagged it under [betrayal-at-house-on-hill](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/betrayal-at-house-on-hill) and flagged to get help from the Mods (thanks Joe W!) who created the BaBG tag and removed the BaHoH from the Q.

We're having a discussion on whether both tags should be kept.

The thing is... while they are different individual games, there are a lot more gamers familiar with Betrayal at the House on the Hill and they could potentially provide with insights.

As ikegami puts it:

> *In this case*, the answer is the same for both games, so you could mention that in your answer, so we could dual-tag, so we would help more people.

**Should we use both tags?**

Comment: FYI, flags are only seen by [moderators](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Retagging doesn't require a mod, though, just [150 reputation](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). So while mods *can* of course add tags too, a comment on your question asking for a tag is generally all you need. Plenty of 150-rep users are going to see new questions.

Comment: Yup. Thanks for your comment @Cascabel. I'm aware of that. This post is more about consensus on handling double tags.

Comment: Okay. I said that primarily because you said "flagged to get help from the Mods (thanks Joe W!)" and the mods didn't actually do anything - Joe W isn't a mod.

Comment: @Cascabel ... oh, the flag was because I couldn't _create_ a new tag.

Comment: Yes, I understand why you flagged. I'm just saying that you don't actually have to flag for that purpose, because you don't need a mod. (And clarifying that Joe W did not see your flag.) And indeed, a user with sufficient reputation helped you long before a mod saw the flag. You can still flag if you like, we'll obviously help too, but it's often easier and quicker to just let the community help.

Comment: fyi I just retaged the question because I saw in it that the game you where talking about was different and you couldn't create the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because two games are similar doesn't mean that they should both be tagged on a question where the answer could apply to both of them. In my opinion having multiple game tags on a single question can lead to confusion that the games are all expansion/addons and not really help future readers by having both present.